# "Cannot GET /" using nodejs + laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel

I'm using Laravel with nodejs and a couple of npms.

In my server.js I have this code, there are no errors shown in console only my "Server Listening at port 3000" message, however, I keep getting "Cannot GET /".

Can't find whats wrong with my code, please help.

```
var socket  = require( './public/node_modules/socket.io' );
var express = require('./public/node_modules/express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on( 'new_count_message', function( data ) {
    io.sockets.emit( 'new_count_message', { 
        new_count_message: data.new_count_message

    });
  });

  socket.on( 'update_count_message', function( data ) {
    io.sockets.emit( 'update_count_message', {
        update_count_message: data.update_count_message 
    });
  });

  socket.on( 'new_message', function( data ) {
    io.sockets.emit( 'new_message', {
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        subject: data.subject,
        created_at: data.created_at,
        id: data.id
    });
  });


});
```

Here is my routing:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('send');
});
Route::post('/','SendController@postCreate');
Route::get('message','MessageController@index');
Route::post('message','MessageController@updateSeen');
```

My send.blade.php file is a simple static page.

Comment: Where's the php part that interact with server.js?

Comment: Where do you keep getting `cannot get /`?

Comment: I get "cannot get /" when going to: http://localhost:3000/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki This interaacts with a message.blade.php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are only running a nodejs server, are you sure you are running your laravel server too?

Keep your port as it was and check your laravel app in port 80.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Your server is listening , but it seems that, as you didn't assigned anything to your **app** var ( no routes, no static file serving middleware, etc), once a request come in, nobody is doing anything yo serve it.

The port is open, and listening, but nobody is answering

Comment: It is, look at the 4th line: var server  = require('http').createServer(app), I updated the question

Comment: .@bob-xplosion Sorry didn't understood the whole environment first time